# Calculate $\int \limits {x^n \over 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}} dx$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Calculate $$\int \limits {x^n \over 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+...+\frac{x^n}{n!}} dx$$ where $n$ is a positive integer.

Would you give me a hint?

Comment: The denominator is the first values of the Taylor expansion for $e^x$, but I doubt that that helps.

Comment: Usually you want to start by factorizing the denominator, but I don't think this is possible here... Maybe use induction: let $P_n$ be the denominator, then $P_{n+1}' = P_n$ might help you integrate by parts (?). Do you want to compute a finite integral, or a primitive (I am quite pessimistic about the integrability by usual functions) ?

Comment: [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+x^n%2F%28summation+from+k%3D0+to+k%3Dn+of+%28x^k%2Fk!%29%29)

Ain't gonna be that easy.

Comment: @Chris, looking at the answers I am both ashamed of my comment and I realized that this integral was pretty easy. Wolfram was just complicating things after simplifying the expression.

Comment: A general piece of advice (to the question "How to start?"): Try it out with small values of $n$!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ooh, the solution is actually cute! Let's write $P_n$ for the denominator. The numerator $x^n$ is a simple linear combination of $P_n$ and $P_n'$:
$$ x^n = n! (P_n - P_n').$$
Using this, you can simplify to a form which is very easy to integrate!

Comment: It is cute, and surprisingly easy! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14):

Hint:
If $p_n(x)=1+x+\cdots+x^n/n!$ then $p'_n(x)=p_n(x)-x^n/n!$. Therefore
$$
\frac{x^n}{p_n(x)}=n!\frac{p_n(x)-p'_n(x)}{p_n(x)}.
$$

Comment: The formula for $p_n'(x)$ is, indeed, familiar to us from the Taylor series of $e^x$.